# How to check references for buffers provided from a PooledByteBufallocator?

Tags: netty

Using Netty 4, is there a way to see how many ByteBuf's are unreleased (still allocated) from a PooledByteBufAllocator?

The reason I'm looking for this is mainly for unit testing, so that I can provide a PooledByteBufAllocator into a handler/pipeline on the channel (using an EmbeddedChannel), and ensure that after the handler or pipeline completes that all requested/created pooled ByteBufs have been released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way at the moment. I think this will be part of https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1586

Comment: Thanks Norman, I've added to the issue for a request to have a version of the PooledbyteBufAllocator (or on that implementation) to be able to check for references for unit testing purposes.